# Heroku Rails App Deploy - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: heroku, puma

I must have done something. We have two heroku apps - app-prod and app-uat, after trying to deploy the UAT version of the code to the prod app, the deployment completes, but whenever a user accesses the app, in the trail logs, I can see the following:

```
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210569+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/dsl.rb:133:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210581+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/dsl.rb:133:in `_load_from'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210582+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:237:in `block in load'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210582+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:237:in `each'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210582+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:237:in `load'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210582+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:54:in `initialize'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210582+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:66:in `new'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210583+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:66:in `initialize'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210583+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/bin/puma:8:in `new'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210583+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-6.3.0/bin/puma:8:in `<top (required)>'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210584+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/bin/puma:25:in `load'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.210584+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/local/bundle/bin/puma:25:in `<main>'
2023-12-04T21:21:08.304550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is. Deploying the same code to UAT works flawlessly, but when deployed to PROD, it seems like the Procfile initiating the /config/puma.rb crashes.

Any help would be appreciated